# Shift Register 74HC595 Output Current

Tags: c++, arduino, teensy

I'm testing/debugging a C++ program that uses the 74HC595 shift register (Arduino Teensy3.2 @ 3.3V).

I want to connect the 8 outputs of the SR back to 8 input pins on the Arduino board.

**My question is:** would I need resistors between the output of the shift register and the Arduino input? How to know the current flowing from the SR output?

I did have a look at the datasheet but that just confused me more:
https://www.taydaelectronics.com/datasheets/A-251.pdf

CODE TO SET THE REGISTERS:

```
void ShiftRegisterOut(uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST)
        digitalWrite(pinData, !!(val & (1 << i)));
    else    
        digitalWrite(pinData, !!(val & (1 << (7 - i))));
    digitalWrite(pinClock, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(pinClock, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam language tags, C and C++ are very different things.

Comment: You should just measure it. I also recommend learning more than basic electronics, you'll need it handling these kind of things

Comment: @nada just wasn't sure which tag to put. actually the languages are very similar - just that C does not support classes and objects.

Comment: Please be careful, it's not that simple. Some people get very emotional about it

Comment: This question is more about the hardware than about software. Also, there is a dedicated site for questions about the Arduino, perhaps you should move the question there: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your example code could be valid in both languages, that is correct, but your question is rather about electronics, so maybe use neither tag.

Answer (score 2):

According to the datasheet you linked and the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/K20P64M72SF1.pdf) for uC on the Teensy you should not need resistors between the uC to limit current:

74HC595 maximum output current +/-20mA @ 6V

MK20DX256VLH7 maximum input current +/- 25mA

But if you supply the 74HC595 with > 6V you might exceed the maximum input voltage of 5.5V of the MK20DX256VLH7.

Comment: What you found for the 74HC595 is the maximum clamp current, not the maximum allowed output current. The latter is 35mA.

Answer (score 2):

We need to differentiate between "µC port is input" and "µC port is output", and how the supply voltages differ.

**TL;DR:** You should strive to use the same supply voltage on both, and to make sure that the µC never sets the connected port pins as output. This is the first case described, and you will need no resistor.

## µC port is input

#### Supply voltage of 74HC595 is *lower than or equal to* that of the µC

In this case the input impedance of the µC port is so high that no significant DC current flows.

You don't need any resistor, it will only make the edges slower.

#### Supply voltage of 74HC595 is *higher than* that of the µC

If the voltage output by the pins of the 74HC595 makes the clamp diodes of the µC conduct, the resulting current *can* be too high, depending on too many electrical characteristics to mention here. The data sheet of the 74HC595 states that each output can deliver **at least** 35mA because this is the allowed maximum output current. This is clearly more then the allowed 25mA of the µC.

There is another limit: the 74HC595 must not provide more than 70mA in total.

So you need a resistor per line. For optimum speed of the edges make it as low as possible.

In example, if you have 6V supply at the 74HC595, you will need at least (6V - 3.3V) / (70mA / 8) = 308Ohm. To be safe I'd use 620Ohm.

## µC port is output

In this case the output could drive against each other. You need a resistor for each line. The higher of both supply voltages needs to be taken into account.

The µC has the limit for the sum of all outputs, too: it must not provide more than 100mA in total. But this is higher than that of the 74HC595 so we need to take that.

#### Supply voltage of 74HC595 is *lower than or equal to* that of the µC

The critical case is "low" on the 74HC595 and "high" on the µC.

You will need at least 3.3V / (70mA / 8) = 377Ohm. To be safe I'd use 750Ohm.

#### Supply voltage of 74HC595 is *higher than* that of the µC

The critical case is "high" on the 74HC595 and "low" on the µC, and it depends on the supply voltage of the 74HC595.

In example, if you have 6V supply at the 74HC595, you will need at least 6V / (70mA / 8) = 686Ohm. To be safe I'd use 1.5kOhm.